# How can I retrieve text, line by line, from 'contenteditable' to variables in pure javascript, no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print text from a div having contenteditable to another div. I just want to find out how one line can be printed and then I can put it in loop.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var t1 = t.value;
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = t1;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = t1;
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
}

#textbox,
#div1,
#div2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t1 = t.innerHTML;
```

instead of

```
var t1 = t.value;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `value` attribute for div. Use `t.textContent;` or `innerHTML`

```js
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var t1 = t.textContent;
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = t1;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = t1;
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
}

#textbox,
#div1,
#div2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Syed Mohamed Aladeen, and all who helped in  solving it, now it's working fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I click enter or return, it does not go to the next line. I tried to put \r and \n on the end of the string, it didn't work. Any suggestion.

Comment: I solved the problem for the next line. In the class subbox, i removed flex and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get value, but value does not exist, instead, grab the inner HTML when assigning to the variable t1

```
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var t1 = t.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = t1;
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = t1;
});
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.innerText` instead of `.value`.

> just saw the above answers you can also use `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var t1 = t.innerText;
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = t1;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = t1;
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
}

#textbox,
#div1,
#div2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```