# In contenteditablle, only the first line is filtering regular expression and the second failed to filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

in reference to my previous question:

[How can I retrieve text, line by line, from 'contenteditable' to variables in pure javascript, no jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896924/how-can-i-retrieve-text-line-by-line-from-contenteditable-to-variables-in-pu)

The first line in in the div1 and div2 is filtered with the regular expression and the second line not filtered and it is printed as it is in the textbox.

This I am trying to  develop a markdown previewer in pure JavaScript.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var t1 = t.textContent;
  var h1 = t1.replace("/[#]{1}(.+)/g", "<h1>$1</h1>");
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = h1;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = h1;
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid #981b1e;
}

#textbox,
#div1,
#div2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="subbox" id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="subbox" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your regular expression is wrapped in quotes, so it is merely a string and not a RegEx at all - is this just a typo in your example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I got it right, what you want to do is:

1 -  to print the first line of the input inside div1, filtered by the regular expression.

2 - to print the second line of the input inside div2 without filtering.

What I would do is split by newline character and process each line separately.

```
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var t1 = t.textContent;
  //something like:
  var t1_array = t1.split("\n");
  var line1 = t1_array[0];
  var line2 = t1_array[1];

  var h1 = line1.replace("/[#]{1}(.+)/g", "<h1>$1</h1>");
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = h1;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = line2;
});
```

(Not tested. Just trying to give some orientation)

Comment: If you see the snippet, i don' want to print # in div1 and div2, but want to print rest of the string.

Comment: I tried and but didn't  work. Though your solution makes sense. I used JSON.stringify(h1). The text in contenteditable shows all one line and it is not splitting. In testbox I typed: #test 
                                            #test and it was printed in div 1

Comment: I tried and but didn't  work. Though your solution makes sense. I used JSON.stringify(h1). The text in contenteditable shows all in one line and it is not splitting. In testbox I typed: #test 
                                            #test and it was printed in div 1 as:                                                                           "
test
#test 
"